# Ansible local changes not getting reflected while running the playbook

Tags: ansible

I modified an Ansible play-book, and from git status I can clearly see the modified data/files. Now when I run the play-book, the changes do not come into effect even after the play-book has run completely.
I tried renaming the playbook file, and even removing the play-book file form the directory, still the play-book executes. Seems some sort of caching mechanism.

I often end up in this situation but not able to understand what goes wrong. Ansible version used is 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I had multiple path entries in the ansible.cfg for roles_path parameter. Co-incidentally, for each path specified in the roles_path parameter, the repository also existed and as per design Ansible used the first match.

Hence every time I made changes in my repository, still the data would come from the other repositories.